# Is there anyway to check whether the google account that user integrated is a Google workspace account(Gsuite) or normal account?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, integration

I'm trying to create an app which uses google calendar api and can block dates on calendars of all persons of an organization and to do that I need to integrate with the google workspace account of the organization, I want to add a check so that the user have to integrate with only G suite account. But I'm not able to find whether the account integrated is google workspace(G suite) or normal account.

Answer (score 1):

To restrict sign-ins to users of your own organization's Cloud Identity or Workspace account, you can [set the OAuth consent screen to internal](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en#:%7E:text=limit%20authorization%20requests%20to%20members%20of%20the%20organization).

Alternatively, you can request the scopes `openid email` and check the [`hd` claim in the resulting ID Token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect). This claim contains the primary domain name of the user's Cloud Identity/Workspace account. If the claim is missing, it's a consumer account.

Comment: Thank you, But I need to know whether the google account that the user is integrating with is an admin account or not, because if it is not google workspace admin account, I wont be able to access the calendars of other users under that domain. Any Solution for knowing whether the account is admin or not with userProfile and email scopes

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this documentation once.
[Who is my adminstrator](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960).

[image]

So it is not possible to get the admin of Gsuite as per my knowledge.
Please correct me if I am wrong.